# failed to write digest data in docker image while pulling

Tags: docker

I am getting an error while try to pull an image from local registry

```
failed to write digest data: open  ..... no such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

i have tried to pull after removing the docke root directry solved the problem. But still what if i dont want tpo remove my docker root directory?